# Update nginx to latest version 1.24.0 in dockerfile

Tags: docker, nginx, debian, version

I have a dockerfile that uses php:8.1-fpm as the base image which uses debian 12. This image is helping me install nginx version 1.22.1. Not due to security vulnerabilities, I need to upgrade nginx to 1.24.0.

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx=1.24.* \
```

But this is giving me error as 1.24.* version not found.

Then I tried adding ppa repository and upgrading the nginx using information from this link:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

```
nginx=stable # use nginx=development for latest development version
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx
apt update
apt install nginx
```

But still no success. I am still getting nginx 1.22.1

Is there any way by which I can upgrade nginx in my docker image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now **mainline** nginx version is 1.25.1, **stable** verion is 1.24.0

Create Dockerfile for mainline nginx version

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt update && apt -y install curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release debian-archive-keyring
RUN curl https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian `lsb_release -cs` nginx" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
RUN apt update && apt -y install nginx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 80/tcp
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Build image

```
$ docker build . -t nginx-mainline-php81
```

Check images

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nginx-mainline-php81    latest    8768a3a02d01   9 minutes ago   525MB
```

Check OS, nginx and php versions in docker

```
$ docker run nginx-mainline-php81 cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 12 \n \l

$ docker run nginx-mainline-php81 nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.25.1

$ docker run nginx-mainline-php81 php -v
PHP 8.1.20 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2023 05:51:39) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.20, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Run container as daemon

```
$ docker run -d --rm -p 90:80 nginx-mainline-php81
54a76f657d71024d95e3c4fae5f18b18b0040bbbab5ab17ecb0076468fd59f09
```

We mapping port 90 of host to the port 80 docker container. Check *netstat*:

```
$ netstat -tupln | grep 90
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:90   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  28520/docker-proxy
tcp6   0   0 :::90        :::*       LISTEN  28527/docker-proxy
```

Go to the browser and open address SERVER_IP:90, you can see nginx defaul page. Or check with curl from command line, like:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:90
```

You will see html *source code* of the nginx defaul page.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a fantastic answer. I was able to upgrade nginx to 1.24.0. But is there a way where I could remove the default nginx page shown after the docker compose up and take the URL to my drupal application as previous.

Comment: Use VOLUMES in docker-compose.yml to map host dirs and files to container, some like: `volumes: - /local/path/to/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro`